# Does socket expires?

Tags: php

I will do a long time sleep after I create a $socket and then do a `socket_sendto`.
Will it work?
Or should I do a `socket_create` and `socket_sendto` everytime?

```
<?php
$server_ip   = '127.0.0.1';
$server_port = 12345;
$message = "test";
if ($socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP)) {
  while(true) {
    sleep(get_sleep_time()); // get_sleep_time return random time > 100000 seconds
    socket_sendto($socket, $message, strlen($message), 0, $server_ip, $server_port);
  }
} else {
  print("can't create socket\n");
}
?>
```

Comment: There's only one way to really know and it's by trying it out! Thus said, sockets do not expire. That's why you should `close` the connection after you are finished, when you are finished.

Answer (score 0):

Sockets do not expire until they are closed by the client in other words socket_close(). That should work fine.